# Cannot update read/write attributes of UserPoolClient via C# SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

When programmatically creating a Cognito user pool and app client, if the app client is to have read/write access to attributes of the user pool, that access must be explicitly given. I have been able to do so successfully for custom attributes but built-in attributes always return an error of "Invalid write attributes specified while creating a client" or "Invalid read attributes specified while creating a client".

Documentation is ... both voluminous and difficult to find. I have yet to see an example of this or an actual bit of useful documentation on the  CreateUserPoolClientRequest type that says anything about this other than things like "ReadAttributes is a list of strings that are the attributes that can be read".

Here is the code I'm using that always ends up with that error message and failure to create the app client. _client is an AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient properly instantiated and credentialed and running in a lambda function.

```
var request = new CreateUserPoolClientRequest { UserPoolId = userPoolId, ClientName = $"{name}AppClient" };

var builtInAttributes = new List<string>()
        {
            "address","birthdate","email","family name","gender","given name","locale","middle name","name","nickname","phone number", "picture","preferred username","profile","zoneinfo","updated at","website"
        };

var readAttributes = new List<string>();
var writeAttributes = new List<string>();

readAttributes.InsertRange(0,builtInAttributes);
writeAttributes.InsertRange(0, builtInAttributes);

var attributeConfig = ConfigurationHelper.GetListFromSection("UserPoolCustomAttributes");

foreach (var attribute in attributeConfig)
{
   readAttributes.Add($"custom:{attribute.Key}");
   writeAttributes.Add($"custom:{attribute.Key}");

}

request.ReadAttributes = readAttributes;
request.WriteAttributes = writeAttributes;

var result = await _client.CreateUserPoolClientAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Though I have yet to find it documented anywhere, default attributes with a space in the name in the ui need to have that space replaced with an underscore when using their name in the api.

Comment: Not sure if they were in here at the time but they are all now here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html